# Problem with WEB3J Maven Plugin, it cant find the solidity compiler

Tags: java, maven, web3-java

I use the web3j maven plugin to auto generate the Smart Contract Java Proxies.

But I have the problem, that the solidity compiler version couldn't be found.

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- web3j-maven-plugin:4.8.2:generate-sources (default) @ web3j-client-lib ---
[INFO] Solidity: adding to process 'DZPayments.sol'
[INFO] Solidity: adding to process 'Migrations.sol'
[INFO] Solidity: adding to process 'Proxy.sol'
[INFO] Solidity: adding to process 'Storage.sol'
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  26.928 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-18T10:50:37+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to get solidity version from server
```

Has anyone an idea?

I'm using only default config and have copied the SOL Files to src/main/resources

This is my plugin config (easiest possible!):

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
        <artifactId>web3j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <soliditySourceFiles/>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I used the following two dependencies with version 4.8.4 but I tested it with 5.0.0 too with the same result:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
    <artifactId>abi</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.web3j</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: btw do you know if its possible for the web3j-maven-plugin plugin to simply reference abi files (that were already generated by a separate truffle project) and simply create the Java proxies from those ? or do I have to tell webj3 to compile everything all over again ?

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem. We solved it by manually performing some steps of the maven plugin:

1. Go to the solidity versions list posted here: https://internal.services.web3labs.com/api/solidity/versions/.
2. Save the displayed json as `releases.json` in `~/.web3j/solc/`.
3. Manually search the list of binaries download the one you need (i.e. win/linux/mac).
4. Save the selected binary in a subfolder using the version as its name. For example, if you need version `0.4.25` create a corresponding folder (`~/.web3j/solc/0.4.25/`) and put the binaries there.
5. Rerun your maven build.

Somehow, the problem is that the maven plugin is not able to download the corresponding files. After doing that manually, the plugin finds the binaries and skips downloading them.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that link https://internal.services.web3labs.com/api/solidity/versions/ **doesn't exist anymore** so use this link to download releases.json file:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/web3j/web3j-sokt/master/src/main/resources/releases.json

**Solution found on** https://github.com/web3j/web3j-maven-plugin/issues/68 posted by **doumuxie**. This is domuxie's translation from Chinese to English by using Google Translate to prevent link-rot (as commented by lugiorgi):

*If the sol version is compiled beyond 0.7.1, the above problem will occur. The reason is because web3j will first obtain the latest windows available URL from the local C:\Users.web3j\solc\release.json, in maven web3j 4.9. In version 4, the sub-dependency web3j-sokt 0.2.1 was introduced, in the source code https://github.com/web3j/web3j-sokt/blob/release/0.2.1/src/main/kotlin/org/web3j/ Available in sokt/VersionResolver.kt, you can see that the release.json file was downloaded from https://internal.services.web3labs.com/api/solidity/versions/, but the windows_url in the file has been "" since 0.7.1, so Unable to find suitable compiled version solc.*

*In web3j-sokt 0.2.2 https://github.com/web3j/web3j-sokt/blob/release/0.2.2/src/main/kotlin/org/web3j/sokt/VersionResolver.kt, release.json The download address has been changed to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/web3j/web3j-sokt/master/src/main/resources/releases.json. The latest available version in the file so far is solidity 0.8.13.
So I think the solution should be to exclude web3j-sokt 0.2.1 from maven and introduce the new web3j-sokt 0.2.2.*

Comment: It would be better to add the translated solution here to prevent link-rot in the future.